# Projectives and Injectives in Functor Categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

Would it be possible to enlighten me (or even better give a reference) about enough projectives (injectives) in functor categories?

Here is a precise question. Let $C$ be a small category, whose total morphism set has cardinality $\alpha$. Let $A$ be an abelian category with enough projectives (dually, injectives) and coproducts (products) up to cardinality $\alpha$. The functor category $A^C$ is clearly abelian.

**Question** Does $A^C$ have enough projectives (dually, injectives)?

A reference would be ideal but an explanation would be very welcome too. I am getting fricasseeed this morning by this question: surely, the issue should be whether one can cover an object in $A$ by a projective object functorially but I have no idea how to spell it out...

Comment: Even if you could choose a functorial projective cover in $\mathcal{A}$, there is still the fact that diagrams that are componentwise projective need not be projective. For instance, $\mathcal{C}$ could be the category freely generated by one endomorphism and $\mathcal{A}$ could be the category of $k$-vector spaces; then a diagram $\mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{A}$ is the same thing as a $k [x]$-module.

Comment: @ZhenLin Moreover: If one chooses $\mathcal{A}$ to be the category of *finite dimensional* $k$-vector spaces, then $\mathcal{A}$ has enough projective for the cardinality of $Ob(\mathcal{C})=\{\ast\}$ but there are no finite dimensional $k[x]$-modules.

Comment: If $A$ were a Grothendieck category the answer would be yes, even under smaller assumptions. I wonder what you have in mind when you require $A$ to have just 'very small' (co)products.

Comment: Good point and a counter-example too: take your $C$ and $A$ the category of finite dimensional vector spaces... I am editing the question to address this.

Comment: @ Fernando: what is the reference for this? I am kind of see why this helps with injectives (probably, $A^C$ will be Grothendieck too, will it not?) but I am not sure about projectives...

Comment: @BugsBunny: Yes, it's also Grothendieck. Projectives are easy, they are just 'tensor products' of representables and projectives in $A$. It's actually the easiest part and doesn't need the strength of Grothendieck categories. As for references, if the target is Ab then probably Freyd's book on abelian categories. Otherwise Ulmer maybe?

Comment: I believe this sort of thing was done by Charles Watts in "A homology theory for small categories" [Proc. Conf. Categorical Algebra, La Jolla; Springer (1966) 331-335]. I don't remember the details, nor do I have the paper handy, but the MathSciNet review sounds as though this paper may be relevant.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For each object $c$ in $\mathcal{C}$, let $c^* : [\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{A}] \to \mathcal{A}$ be evaluation at $c$. It is an exact functor, so if a left adjoint $c_! : \mathcal{A} \to [\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{A}]$ exists, $c_!$ will preserve projective objects. Assume $\mathcal{C}$ has $\le \alpha$ morphisms and $\mathcal{A}$ has coproducts for families of $\le \alpha$ objects. Then the left adjoint $c_!$ exists and can be computed the following formula:
$$(c_! A) (c') = \mathcal{C} (c, c') \odot A$$
(Here, $X \odot A$ denotes the coproduct of $X$-many copies of $A$.)

Now, let $F$ be an object in $[\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{A}]$. For each object $c$ in $\mathcal{C}$, choose a projective cover $P_c \twoheadrightarrow F c$. By adjointness, we obtain morphisms $c_! P_c \to F$ in $\mathcal{A}$; note that  the composite $P_c \to c^* c_! P_c \to F c$ is the epimorphism we started with, so $c^* c_! P_c \to F$ is an epimorphism in particular. Now, form the object $P = \bigoplus_{c \in \operatorname{ob} \mathcal{C}} c_! P_c$; then there is a morphism $P \to F$ such that the components $P c \to F c$ are all epimorphisms. Furthermore, each $c_! P_c$ is projective, and the class of projective objects is closed under coproducts, so we have obtained the required projective cover of $F$.

I'm afraid I do not have a reference, but the above is essentially the same as the proof that (say) $[\mathcal{C}, \mathbf{Ab}]$ has enough projectives. It can be further generalised to the case where $\mathcal{C}$ is preadditive and $[\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{A}]$ is the category of additive functors.